# C++ macro defining classes dependent on each other

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to write macro that defines two tightly connected classes at once, but I cannot. Here is my code:

```
#ifndef SIGNALS_HPP
#define SIGNALS_HPP

#include <unordered_set>
#include <cstdio>

/**
  * Macro defines pair of classes, sender and receiver. When one of them is destroyed, 
  * all it's connections are dully unconnected.
  * 
  * EXAMPLE:
  * 
  *     signal(SomeEvent, some_event_occured)
  * 
  * EXPANDS TO:
  *     
  *     class SomeEventReceiver {
  *     protected:
  *         virtual void on_some_event_occured() {}
  *     }
  * 
  *     class SomeEventSender {
  *     public:
  *         void connect_some_event_occured(SomeEventReceiver & listener);  // registers listener
  *         void unconnect_some_event_occured(SomeEventReceiver & listener);  // forgets listener
  *     
  *     protected:
  *         void send_some_event_occured();  // notifies all listeners
  *     }
  */

#define signal(signal_name, slot_name)\
    class signal_name##Sender;\
    \
    class signal_name##Receiver\
    {\
        friend class signal_name##Sender;\
        std::unordered_set<signal_name##Sender*> senders;\
        \
    protected:\
        virtual void on_##slot_name() {}\
        \
    public:\
        virtual ~signal_name##Receiver();\
    };\
    \
    \
    class signal_name##Sender\
    {\
        friend class signal_name##Receiver;\
        std::unordered_set<signal_name##Receiver*> listeners;\
        \
    public:\
        virtual ~signal_name##Sender()\
        {\
            for (auto i : listeners)\
                i->senders.erase(this);\
            listeners.clear();\
        }\
        \
        void connect_##slot_name(signal_name##Receiver & listener)\
        {\
            listeners.insert(&listener);\
            listener.senders.insert(this);\
        }\
    \
        void unconnect_##slot_name(signal_name##Receiver & listener)\
        {\
            listeners.erase(&listener);\
            listener.senders.erase(this);\
        }\
        \
    protected: \
        void send_##slot_name()\
        {\
            for (auto i : listeners)\
                i->on_##slot_name();\
        }\
        \
    };\
    \
    /*\ //  <--------------  THE LAST SECTION
    signal_name##Receiver::~signal_name##Receiver()\
    {\
        for (auto i : senders)\
            i->listeners.erase(this);\
        senders.clear();\
    }//*/\




#endif // SIGNALS_HPP
```

1) Why it does work with the last section commented? I thought that all virtual methods must be either defined or pure?

2) This macro is used in another header. When the last section is uncommented I receive a lot of "multiple definition" errors. I belive I know why it does not work: the last section counts as definition and should not be in header. But then how can I implement such macro? Or if I'm mistaken, what is the real problem?

Quick usage example:

```
#ifndef SOME_HPP
#define SOME_HPP

signal(AA, aa)

class X : public AASender {
};

#endif
```

If something like that is included (maybe indirectly) in a few .cpp files it gets errors of kind:
"multiple definition of `typeinfo for AAReceiver', first defined here, In function`~new_allocator':". "`typeinfo" varies to destructor and`type name and vtable. AAReciver sometimes becomes AASender.

If someone really likes reading there are real errors:

```
army.o: In function `~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
army.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
army.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
army.o: In function `std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<BattleEndaaaaaaaSender*, false> > >::_M_deallocate_nodes(std::__detail::_Hash_node<BattleEndaaaaaaaSender*, false>*)':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
army.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo name for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
army.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `vtable for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
game.o: In function `~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
game.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
game.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
game.o: In function `vector':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
game.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo name for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
game.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `vtable for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
gamemapwidget.o: In function `~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
gamemapwidget.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
gamemapwidget.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
gamemapwidget.o: In function `std::_Hashtable<BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver*, BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver*, std::allocator<BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver*>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver*>, std::hash<BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver*>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, true, true> >::_M_erase(std::integral_constant<bool, true>, BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver* const&)':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
gamemapwidget.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo name for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
gamemapwidget.o: In function `new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `vtable for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
battle.o: In function `~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
battle.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
battle.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver::~BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver()'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
battle.o: In function `std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<BattleEndaaaaaaaSender*, false> > >::_M_deallocate_nodes(std::__detail::_Hash_node<BattleEndaaaaaaaSender*, false>*)':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
battle.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `typeinfo name for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
battle.o: In function `~new_allocator':
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: multiple definition of `vtable for BattleEndaaaaaaaReceiver'
province.o:/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/build-Universania-Desktop-Debug/../Universania/battle.hpp:10: first defined here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please consider using `template` instead. There are so many things that could go wrong. Unlike many others', your macro is formatted neatly, but conceptually, it remains a mess.

Comment: Can you add the macro use to your post; also the exact error message?  Thanks.

Comment: So your problem description amounts to "I cannot". Nice, lots of detail there.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using a library to give the functionality you want - such as Boost Signals, or Qt.

Comment: Do not do it. Have a look at libsigc++, boost::signal2 or similar

Comment: Search the web for "Macros are evil".  Read the articles.  Don't use MACROS unless absolutely necessary.  MACROs for saving typing strokes are usually considered evil and worthless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An out-of-line function definition in a header will be emited with every compilation unit that includes that header, hence the multiple definitions. Simply make it `inline` to avoid that.

Btw, this has nothing to do with your macro. Macros should be avoided in C++. Except for include guards and conditional compilation, there are almost no sensible macro usages in C++. Many things can be better done with templates.

Comment: I second this. Using templates this should be straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my main question. As to macros, I'm using them as copy-paste with parameters, and that, I believe, is what they were invented for. In my design these classes are in no way related, they are only identical. By the way, I'm stlill interested in my first question, from what I read and experienced it should result in linker "undefined reference to vtable" error.

Comment: instantinations of template classes are also *in no way related, they are only identical*, for example `template<int tag> class SomeClass {...};`: the two classes `SomeClass<0>` and `SomeClass<1>` can be identical yet unrelated (cannot be cast to each other). Macros were invented before C++ and for C, which does not have templates.